# Conditionally build go sources for x86 and mips

Tags: go

I have some go sources that are exclusively built for mips. I'm trying to get them to compile on x86 so as to run select, non-architecture-specific code on x86 as well. My sources are organized as below:

ipmi.go: # Only builds on mips.

```
package main

import (
    "foo"
    "bar"
)

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lfreeipmi
#define FOO 1
some c code
*/

import C
// go code
func gofunc1() {
}

func gofunc2() {
}
// more go code
```

hardware.go: # All go code

```
package main
import (
         "lots"
          "of"
          "libs"
        )

func main() {
    // some go code
    ret1 = gofunc1() 
    ret2 = gofunc1() 

    // Use ret1 and ret2 to do something else.
    // more go code
}
```

What's the best way to enable building these sources on x86?

I added the following to ipmi.go to restrict the arch on which it is built:

```
// +build linux,mips,cgo
```

hardware.go still fails to compile since it calls `gofunc1()` and `gofunc2()`. Since hardware.go will always need to call `gofunc1()` and `gofunc2()`, I can't think
of any way to conditionally compile these sources for x86. Any inisghts will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Package build](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)
>
> **Build Constraints**
>
> A build constraint, also known as a build tag, is a line comment that
>   begins
>
> ```
> // +build
> ```
>
> that lists the conditions under which a file should be included in the
>   package. Constraints may appear in any kind of source file (not just
>   Go), but they must appear near the top of the file, preceded only by
>   blank lines and other line comments. These rules mean that in Go files
>   a build constraint must appear before the package clause.
>
> To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, a series
>   of build constraints must be followed by a blank line.
>
> To build a file only when using cgo, and only on Linux and OS X:
>
> ```
> // +build linux,cgo darwin,cgo
> ```
>
> Such a file is usually paired with another file implementing the
>   default functionality for other systems, which in this case would
>   carry the constraint:
>
> ```
> // +build !linux,!darwin !cgo
> ```

Follow the suggestion in the documentation. For example,

`hardware.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ipmi())
}
```

`ipmi.go`:

```
// +build linux,mips,cgo

package main

func ipmi() string { return "mips" }
```

`ipmi_not.go`:

```
// +build !linux !mips !cgo

package main

func ipmi() string { panic("not implemented") }
```